# Postman shows no response to Laravel Middleware Exceptions

Tags: api, laravel, http, postman

I'm having some trouble getting this middleware to work in Laravel. I'm using Tymon's JWT to check if a token is valid, but when I test with Postman I get no response at all instead of the HTTP 4xx error I have set.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{

    try {

        JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {       //Token Expired
        return response('Token Expired', 440);
    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {       //Token Invalid
        return response('Token Invalid', 401);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        echo("TEST");
        return response('Token Exception', 499);
    } catch (TokenBlacklistedException $e) {   //Token Blacklisted
        return response('Token Blacklisted', 403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When I try to use no token in the header of a Postman call, it tells me there is no response from the server.

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to api.website.dev/test.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
   Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
   Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Client certificates are required for this server:
   Fix this by adding client certificates in Settings > Certificates
Request timeout:
   Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

The exception seems to be triggered, but I can only get a reaction from the server when I put something like an echo statement as seen in the code above.
I've been having trouble with this in other parts of my code as well where I can't create a queued job and Postman says the server is not responding with the same `Could not get any response` message.

Is this a problem with Laravel or am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is working perfectly fine. I used Paw instead of Postman and it showed me the proper error codes through HTTP with the right messages. Looks like the problem was with Postman.

Comment: Might be helpful next time to post the version of Postman you're using, and what the regular `curl` response is - just in case it's something like [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2214) or [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1041). Because you're also sending an unusual (non-standard) HTTP response code for your test case, that could also cause issues with testing tools so best to test with a standard responses, like 404.

Comment: This is most likely due to the custom HTTP lib written for Paw that can read the full error code and status message most other libs do not provide this see https://paw.cloud/docs/advanced/http-libraries

Answer (score 0):

One Time I had the same issue. It was caused by a newline at the end of the `"Authorization"` header's value, which I had set manually by copy-pasting the bearer token (which accidentally contained the newline at its end)